# Comparing byte arrays and vectors

Tags: rust

I'm trying to compare a `Vec` of bytes read to the very bytes that were read in to the `Vec`, but I'm having trouble getting the types of the two sides to line up. Here is my code (http://is.gd/goOnYf):

```
use std::io::{Cursor, Read};
// use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn main() {
    let byte_str = b"This is a byte string";
    let mut byte_vec = Vec::new();

    let mut reader = Cursor::new(byte_str.as_ref());
    reader.read_to_end(&mut byte_vec).unwrap();

    // assert_eq!(byte_str, byte_vec);
    // assert_eq!(byte_str, &byte_vec);
    // assert_eq!(byte_str, byte_vec.as_ref());
    // assert_eq!(byte_str, byte_vec.borrow());

    let bv: &[u8] = &byte_vec;
    assert_eq!(byte_str, bv);
}
```

You can see each of my failed attempts to compare them, before I had to force the `Vec`'s type with a `let` binding and compare those.

The first one, `assert_eq!(byte_str, byte_vec)`, failed with:

```
`<std macros>:5:8: 5:33 error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq<collections::vec::Vec<u8>>` is not implemented for the type `&[u8; 21]`
```

So it looks like I need to turn the `Vec` on the RHS in to a `&[u8]`. So I try a shared reference, and get the same error. Then I tried `as_ref()`, but that (and `borrow()`) need type annotations that I don't seem to be able to provide inline:

```
<anon>:13:35: 13:43 error: type annotations required: cannot resolve `collections::vec::Vec<u8> : core::convert::AsRef<_>` [E0283]
```

Is there a simpler way to do this that I'm missing?

**Update:** In writing the question, I did find an answer, but it's still kind of clunky:

```
assert_eq!(byte_str, AsRef::<[u8]>::as_ref(&byte_vec));
```

Is there a better way?

**Update 2:** The answer below only worked with some byte arrays I tried it with, but not all. It turns out that all of the handy traits like `Debug`, `PartialEq`, etc. are only implemented for arrays with <= 32 elements, so this works:

```
assert_eq!(b"01234567890123456789012345678901", &*byte_vec);
```

but this won't:

```
assert_eq!(b"012345678901234567890123456789012", &*byte_vec);
```

so you have to call `as_ref()` on it to make it a slice, for which those traits are implemented:

```
assert_eq!(b"012345678901234567890123456789012".as_ref(), &*byte_vec);
```

Comment: In my case, 190 elements worked too.
""" 
assert_eq!(&*res_bytes, expect_bytes);
"""

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write the following:

```
assert_eq!(byte_str, &*byte_vec);
```

`&*` may look like a no-op, but in fact, [`Deref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) comes into play here and changes the meaning of the unary `*` operator. `&*byte_vec` is therefore equivalent to `&*(byte_vec.deref())`, or just to `byte_vec.deref()`.